# Bus error while registering exception handler using google breakpad

Tags: c++, linux, google-breakpad

I am trying to use google breakpad with my application. But I am getting buserror while doing so.

Sample application:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "client/linux/handler/exception_handler.h"
static bool breakpadDumpCallback(const google_breakpad::MinidumpDescriptor& descriptor, void* context, bool succeeded)
{
    return succeeded;
}


int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World! \n";

    //Adding changes for google breakpad
    static google_breakpad::ExceptionHandler* excHandler = NULL;
    cout << "Here-----------! \n";

    // delete excHandler;

    excHandler = new google_breakpad::ExceptionHandler(google_breakpad::MinidumpDescriptor("/opt/minidumps/"), NULL, breakpadDumpCallback, NULL, true, -1);

    cout << "Registered Google Breakpad exceptionHandler\n";

    int *x = NULL;
    *x = 10;

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting error from below line:

```
excHandler = new google_breakpad::ExceptionHandler(google_breakpad::MinidumpDescriptor("/opt/minidumps/"), NULL, breakpadDumpCallback, NULL, true, -1);
```

Output :

```
Hello World!
Here-----------!
Bus error (core dumped)
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static library (libbreakpad_client.a) which i was using was an incompatible one. That is why it shows bus error. I have replaced it with another one and it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
google_breakpad::MinidumpDescriptor(std::string("/opt/minidumps/"))
```

If it still does not work, try to make your code (exactly) match an existing working example as much as possible:
http://fossies.org/linux/seafile-client/src/crash-handler.cpp